# JasperReport size limit

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is there a way to set a limit on the size of a JasperReport?  We just looked at a WebSphere 6.1 Heapdump and someone tried to create a report and it was 1.5GB of memory in the heap. And it brought our Websphere server to its knees.
Thanks,
T

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with JasperReports, but you could [wrap your I/O streams](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html#compileReportToStream(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to ensure that the amount of data read/written does not exceed a defined limit.

[OutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) example:

```
public class LimitedSizeOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final OutputStream delegate;
    private final long limit;
    private long written = 0L;

    /**
     * Creates a stream wrapper that will throw an IOException if the write
     * limit is exceeded.
     * 
     * @param delegate
     *            the underlying stream
     * @param limit
     *            the maximum number of bytes this stream will accept
     */
    public LimitedSizeOutputStream(OutputStream delegate, long limit) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    private void checkLimit(long byteCount) throws IOException {
        if (byteCount + written > limit) {
            throw new IOException("Exceeded stream size limit");
        }
        written += byteCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        checkLimit(1);
        delegate.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        checkLimit(b.length);
        delegate.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        checkLimit(len);
        delegate.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        delegate.close();
    }

}
```

It is just as easy to wrap an [InputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

Answer (score 1):

JasperReports now has "report governors" that limit the size of report output. For example, you can set these config params:

***`net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages.enabled=[true|false]`***

***`net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages=[integer]`***

See [this posting](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=48376#55622) on the JasperReports forums for more info.

Comment: Another way is to set [REPORT_MAX_COUNT](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#REPORT_MAX_COUNT) report's parameter. `This built-in parameter accepts java.lang.Integer values
representing the number of records from the data source that the engine will process during the report filling. When the internal record counter reaches the specified value, the engine will assume that it has reached the last record from the data source and will
stop the iteration through the rest of the data source.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried limiting the rows in the recordset returned from the database?