# Break the PDF document after 100 pages

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with JasperReports and iReport tool. One of the requirements the client wants is that the PDF file will be generated to a 100 page document only.

Could you please help me? How can I generated the 100 page PDF document?

Answer (score 2):

As @WEG mentioned in the answer for [JasperReport size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544581/jasperreport-size-limit) question it can be done with help of this parameters:

- [***`net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages.enabled`***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages.enabled) - a flag indicating whether the governor that checks if a report exceeds a specified limit of pages is turned on. With this property enabled, the JR engine will stop the report execution if the number of pages becomes greater than a custom given value;
- [***`net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages`***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages) - if the governor that checks if a report exceeds a specified limit of pages is turned on, this property will indicate the maximum number of pages allowed to be ran, in order to prevent a memory overflow error. If the number of pages in the report becomes greater than this value, the report execution will be stopped;
- [***`REPORT_MAX_COUNT`***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#REPORT_MAX_COUNT) - an integer allowing limit the datasource size.

Answer (score 1):

In the iReport you can find a built in variable PAGE_COUNT. For every element in the detail band you can put the following in the "Print when expression" textbox:

```
Boolean.valueOf($V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() < 100)
```

This will stop printing after page number 100.